# javascript Drag and drop, empty container

Tags: javascript, drag

My goal is to clean any div **.create** and delete any element inside it before I put the edit link inside it, I have tried but I can't.
I have this code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ejmemp

```
<div class="edit"><a class="link_edit" id="4545" href="edit.php?id=xxx" ondragstart="drag(event)">edit</a></div>

<div class="create" ondrop="drop(event,this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><a href="create.php?id=xxx" class="link_create">create</a></div>

<div class="create" ondrop="drop(event,this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><a href="create.php?id=xxx" class="link_create">create</a></div>

<div class="create" ondrop="drop(event,this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><a href="create.php?id=xxx" class="link_create">create</a></div>

<div class="create" ondrop="drop(event,this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><a href="create.php?id=xxx" class="link_create">create</a></div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();                
}

function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev,container){        
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");  
    /*doesn't work*/
    container.innerHTML = "";  
    /*I write clone because I want to keep the original*/            
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It’s `container.innerHTML="";`.

Comment: Thank you. I already edited the question, I added the id to the draggable element an also changed the innerHTML, but now the div .create is cleaned, but the draggable element doesn't appear inside it.

Comment: You shouldn’t correct the code in the question…

Answer (score 2):

*Please note the timing of the edits. The OP has edited in an `id`, and fixed the TypeError with `.innerHTML` after my answer was posted.*

---

If you check your JS console, you'll probably see a whole bunch of these errors.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: container.innerHTML is not a function"
```

This is because `.innerHTML` is a property, but not a *method*. You assign to the property.

```
container.innerHTML = '';
```

Also your draggable element is missing an ID, so

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
```

won't really set anything, which will cause

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
```

to attempt to clone a `null` value. But you shouldn't be cloning unique elements, regardless. (See: [ID attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id))

Consider rethinking the implementation, and definitely look into [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). That much inline JavaScript is cumbersome to work with.

Some reading material:

- [Drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop)
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Thank you. I already edited the question, I added the id to the draggable element an also changed the innerHTML, but now the div .create is cleaned, but the draggable element doesn't appear inside it. –

Comment: You should construct a test case so the folk trying to help you have something more to work with. There are plenty of online tools: http://jsbin.com http://codepen.io/ http://jsfiddle.net/ http://www.webdevout.net/test, or use the code editor here on Stack Overflow.